# Error writes wrong buffer to file using ftell and fseek (C)

Tags: c, ubuntu, fgets, fseek, ftell

I wrote a code that reading line by line from a text file and store the value in a variable called buffer using fgets, after reading each line I am sending the buffer to a function that suppose to replace the content of the buffer as described below, and then it gets written to a target text file.

### function description (I am on ubuntu os)

I have a text file containing fake assembly code, the goal of the function is to save all macros defined in the file in a data structure and then coping the macro content to the target file whenever it used without the macro decleration.

**for example: for source.as**
it will delete the macro decleration

```
mcr m_mcr
 inc r2
 mov A,r1
endmcr
```

**and write the macro content in every place where the macro name is mentioned in the source file**

```
.
.
m_mcr
.
.
```

**after running the function the target file will look like this**

```
.
.
 inc r2
 mov A,r1
.
.
```

**My code works well when using only one macro in the source.as but when defining two the second one is get copied with more gunk to it.**

### Can someone please help me figure out why it is heppening because I am debugging for hours.

here is the function that preformes the algorithm:

```
void processLine(char *buffer, FILE* source)
{
    char* token = NULL;
    char* copy_of_buffer = NULL;
    static char* macro_name;
    static long start_macro_position;
    static long end_macro_position;
    long last_position = 0;
    long content_length = 0;
    macroTable* macro;
    size_t bytes_read = 0;

    /* checking if copy_of_buffer allocated successfully */
    copy_of_buffer = (char*)malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
    FAIL_IF_MSG(copy_of_buffer == NULL, ERROR_ALLOCATION_FAILED);
    
    strcpy(copy_of_buffer, buffer); /* copying the current line to not modify it */
    token = strtok(copy_of_buffer, " \t\n\f\r");
    
    /* checking if token got string (skipping empty lines) */
    RETURN_IF(token == NULL);

    /* checking if the is_mcr flag is on indicating that we are inside of a macro */
    if (is_mcr) {
        /* checking if we reached the end of the macro decleration */
        if (strcmp(token, "endmcr") == 0)
        {
            end_macro_position = ftell(source) - strlen(buffer);
            is_mcr = false;

            /* adding new macro to the macro table */
            insertMacro(macro_name, start_macro_position, end_macro_position);
            free(macro_name);
            /* reseting the macro positions to defualt values */
            start_macro_position = 0;
            end_macro_position = 0;
        }
        /* deleting the line content before writing it to the file */
        memset(buffer, '\0', strlen(buffer));
    }
    else {
        /* seacrhing if using a defined macro */
        macro = lookupMacro(token);

        /* if macro exists in the token name starting coping the content to .am file */
        if (macro != NULL) {
            last_position = ftell(source); /* saving the last position we read from */
            fseek(source, macro->start_position, SEEK_SET); /* going to the start position of the macro in the file */
            content_length = macro->end_position - macro->start_position; /* calulating the content length need to be copied */

            if (MAX_LINE_LENGTH < content_length) {
                /* allocating more memory */
            } else {
                /* deleting the macro name from the buffer */
                memset(buffer, '\0', strlen(buffer));
                /* reading the macro value to the buffer */
                bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, content_length, source);
                /* checking if the content was read successfully */
                if (bytes_read != content_length) {
                    FAIL_IF_MSG(true, ERROR_READING_FROM_FILE);
                }
                /* returning the the last position we were */
                fseek(source, last_position, SEEK_SET);
            }
        } else if (strcmp(token, "mcr") == 0) {
            token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n\f\r");
            FAIL_IF_MSG(token == NULL, DECLERING_MACRO_WITHOUT_NAME);
            
            /* checking if copy_of_buffer allocated successfully */
            macro_name = malloc(strlen(token) + 1); /* + 1 for null terminator */
            FAIL_IF_MSG(macro_name == NULL, ERROR_ALLOCATION_FAILED);
            
            strcpy(macro_name, token);
            is_mcr = true;
            start_macro_position = ftell(source);
            
            /* deleting the line where the mcr decleration was found from the file */
            memset(buffer, '\0', strlen(buffer));
        }
    }
    free(copy_of_buffer);
}
```

##### when running on file.as

```
.define sz = 2
MAIN:   mov r3, LIST[sz]
LOOP:   jmp L1
    mcr m_mcr
        cmp r3, #sz
    bne END
    endmcr
    prn #-5
    mov STR[5], STR[2]
    sub r1, r4
    m_mcr
L1: inc K
    bne LOOP
END:    hlt
.define len = 4
STR:    .string "abcdef"
LIST: .data 6, -9, len
K:  .data 22
```

##### the generated file.am

```
.define sz = 2
MAIN:   mov r3, LIST[sz]
LOOP:   jmp L1
    prn #-5
    mov STR[5], STR[2]
    sub r1, r4
        cmp r3, #sz
    bne END
L1: inc K
    bne LOOP
END:    hlt
.define len = 4
STR:    .string "abcdef"
LIST: .data 6, -9, len
K:  .data 22
```

##### but when running on a file.as with two macros

```
.define sz = 2
MAIN:   mov r3, LIST[sz]
LOOP:   jmp L1
    mcr m_mcr
        cmp r3, #sz
    bne END
    endmcr
    prn #-5
    mcr new_mcr
    mov r1, r3
    endmcr
    mov STR[5], STR[2]
    sub r1, r4
    m_mcr
    new_mcr
L1: inc K
    bne LOOP
END:    hlt
.define len = 4
STR:    .string "abcdef"
LIST: .data 6, -9, len
K:  .data 22
```

##### the generated file.am

```
.define sz = 2
MAIN:   mov r3, LIST[sz]
LOOP:   jmp L1
    prn #-5
    mov STR[5], STR[2]
    sub r1, r4
        cmp r3, #sz
    bne END
    mov r1, r3
z
    bne END
L1: inc K
    bne LOOP
END:    hlt
.define len = 4
STR:    .string "abcdef"
LIST: .data 6, -9, len
K:  .data 22
```

**this is the output I am getting when when printing the macros I saved, as you can see the information is correct**

```
name: m_mcr, start: 62, end: 85, lengh: 23
name: new_mcr, start: 115, end: 127, lengh: 12
```

Comment: Always check the return value of `fseek`, and fail if it fails. Likewise, check the return value of all functions you call.

Comment: I checked it, it is not the problem

Comment: the second macro gets written along with some of the first macro

Comment: You may want to add a full but short C program (not just a single function) so that other StackOverflow users can reproduce your results. Maybe the bug is somewhere else in the program.

Comment: The problem could be in your Insert or Lookup code. Please show a [mre]